# How to set a JS variable from a CSS style

Tags: javascript, css

I've made a bunch of JavaScript functions to show, hide and populate various elements on a zooming menu. All seem to working except for one which I need the function to only run if a CSS setting is a specific value (width of 195%). I am very new to JavaScript so there may be more than one issue here.

```
<script>
  function zoomShowF2() {
    var widthNow = document.getElementById('svg1').style.width;
    if widthNow = '195%' {
      document.getElementById('zoomTitle').style.display = 'flex';
    else
      document.getElementById('zoomTitle').style.display = 'none';
}}</script>
```

Comment: you not closed the parenthesis of the `if`

Comment: about the functionality - for check if equal use double equal sign `==`. and if you meant to check if `less or equal` use `<=`

Comment: I guess what you need is `if widthNow <= '195%'{      document.getElementById('zoomTitle').style.display = 'flex';}  else {      document.getElementById('zoomTitle').style.display = 'none';}`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use comparison operators write the if statement as follows

```js
if (widthNow == '195%') {
```

as the single `=` is assigning the value not comparing it

Answer (score -1):

There are a few issues with your syntax:

```
function zoomShowF2() {
  var widthNow = document.getElementById('svg1').style.width;
  if (widthNow === '195%') {
    document.getElementById('zoomTitle').style.display = 'flex';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('zoomTitle').style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

Comment: Downvoted even though my answer was used by the questioner...SMH.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks everyone. It works now with a combination of the changes suggested. I assume my curly braces are all in 'tidy' positions?

EDIT. I've adjusted the curly brace positions to as per Ed's layout.

Thanks all!

Answer (score -1):

Your code does not called when the element changes it size or width. You must put all your code inside window.onresize event.

```js
var displayOutput = document.getElementById("display-option");

function reportWindowSize() {
  displayOutput.text = document.getElementById("element-to-check").style.width;
}

window.onresize = reportWindowSize;
```

```html
<p id="element-to-check">Resize the browser window to fire the <code>resize</code> event.</p>
<p>Display: <span id="display-option"></span></p>
```